# How to populate select in Ionic Creator

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using [Ionic Creator](https://creator.ionic.io/) for developing an application. While trying to add select (dropdown) I could not see any way to enter options for the dropdown?

Comment: pretty good question :)

Comment: Thank you but I really need to know the solution. I am stuck in middle of development

Answer (score 3):

Simple, but not liked, answer: you can't do it by drag&drop.

If you take a look at the source you get when you download from Ionic Creator, you will see it creates "just" the `select` element:

`<select></select>`

So, you could "kind of fake it", by drag&dropping the `HTML` element inside the `form` element and putting the following code inside:

```
<label class="item item-select" name="myselect">
    <span class="input-label">Input</span>
    <select>

        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

I don't know if in future guys from Ionic will add this. It would be probably worth it if you request it as a feature over at their (very active) forum: http://forum.ionicframework.com/

Comment: Thank you... It can work for now but it is not a solution.

Comment: But it's a correct answer, well at least for now :). As I said, you can go on the Ionic forum and request it as a feature to be added.

Comment: @UmerKhalid the ionic creator is just a way to cut down time on building the general ui for an app. You will not be able to build an app at all using the creator and not doing any coding yourself, or at least not yet.